# Copy the header from one page to another page in PDF using IText

Tags: java, birt, itext7

I have created a PDF using BIRT Report with a header containing a table in each of the data pages. Now using IText I have added Table of Contents to the PDF report. Is there any way to copy the header from the data page to the TOC pages using IText?

Comment: How can a BIRT generated header be recognized? Is it tagged in way usable for the task? Or is it in a separate XObject? Or somehow similarly bundled together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with reasonable effort.

But you could create an empty first page in BIRT (for example, containing a 1x1 grid item of fixed height). Then use iText's PDFStamper class to write the visible TOC to the first page.

The idea can be generalized for the case when the TOC may need more than one page: It should easily be possible to calculate the number of TOC entries in the BIRT report. OTOH if a single TOC entry needs line-wrapping, this information is not enough to calculate the number of pages you need for the TOC.
But it may still suffice to reserve one page for the TOC in BIRT, and if it turns out that the TOC needs more pages (while rendering it with iText), one could clone the whole first page.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly as per my requirement.